# Make nav div sit exactly in the middle between an image and the right side of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a navigation div to sit in the middle between an image and the right page but also in a way that if the browser is resized, will still maintain the relation. I'm quite positive I know how to do it with a relative positioning but I would like to have the navigation fixed.

[image]

[img]   nav   |right side of viewport

```
#wrapperNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 45%;
    right: 50%;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/LLtnZ/3/

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Comment: @elzi hopefully that picture help? I just want the nav to sit on equal distances between the right side of the viewport and the image at all times.

Comment: Do you need to support older IE? This can be done very easily and reliably using flexbox. Any other method is going to be hacky and it gives me a headache just thinking about it.

Comment: No, just current browsers is good enough.

Comment: I'll make a simplified fiddle to get you going...

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox has support in most newer desktop and mobile browsers and really dispenses with a lot of the hackiness involved in trying to maintain alignment and positioning with varying screen sizes; it **flexes**.

For the carousel you describe I would start with the below HTML, based on what you provided in your fiddle:

```
 <div id="wrapper">

    <nav class="nav nav--ready">
        <div class='nav__center'>
            <div class="nav__link nav__link--active">
                <a class="nav__link-bullet" href="#one">1</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__link">
                <a class="nav__link-bullet" href="#two">2</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__link">
                <a class="nav__link-bullet" href="#three">3</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__link">
                <a class="nav__link-bullet" href="#four">4</a>
            </div>

            <div class="nav__link">
                <a class="nav__link-bullet" href="#five">5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class='carousel'>
        <img src="" alt=""/>
    </div>
 </div>
```

`#wrapper` is a flexbox, `.nav` is too, so is `.nav__center`. `#wrapper` is set to `flex-direction: row-reverse;` so as to display navigation on the right, if we added another element to `#wrapper` it would display to the *right* of `.nav`. `.nav` itself is set to `flex-direction: row;`, though it only has one child: `.nav__center`, its flexbox styles of `justify-content: space-around;` and `align-items: center;` keep the nav buttons aligned at its center no matter what. Within `.nav`, `.nav__center` is set to `flex-direction: column;` so its contents display top to bottom, and these styles `align-self: stretch; justify-content: space-around;` distribute each `.nav__link` element evenly from top to bottom.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLtnZ/6/). Notice that navigation stays glued to the right side of the carousel. I set a minimum width on `.nav` so that it won't disappear even when the display is really tiny.

Here is a quick [guide](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) you can probably get through in ten minutes with a cup of coffee.

Comment: The thing is is that I basically need the nav to be fixed while you can still scroll the page because I've got more than one carousel. Wonder if this can be done with js. Thank you for the read though! Very informative.

Comment: just set .nav to position: fixed; and give it a height. And give it a constant width like maybe 50px, since it's not going the adjust anymore. It will still stick to the right edge when the screen is adjusted, just not when scrolling horizontally; since it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative;` to your container which in this case is the nav html element.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLtnZ/4/

Comment: I don't follow. You're demo just shows the same result as mine. Wouldn't the wrapper need to be relative?

Comment: Try to resize the browser window, or maybe I did not understand your question well. Do you need the image to be centered also when resizing?

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. Currently, the image resizes just fine. However, I want the nav to be positioned on the right side of the image at a distance equal to the distance from the right side of viewport.      [IMG] EQUAL [NAV] EQUAL [Right edge of viewport]

Answer (score 0):

This might help. So if your image is is 90% width and centered, that will leave 10% left of pagespace, 5% on either side of the image.

If I understand your drawing correctly, the that would mean you'd want the container your nav is in to be

```
width: 5%
position:fixed;
top: 50%;
right:0;
margin-top -150px;   // half the height
height: 300px;
text-align:center;
```

The 5% width will take up the entire space to the right, but using `text-align:center` will get items in the middle, as per your "equal" annotation on your drawing.

If you need a jsFiddle let me know

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47Q9p/

Comment: If I add that right now all it does is move the entire nav to the left side. Don't I still need a right: xx% ?

Comment: Sorry, see my updated answer. Use background-colors to debug it's position too. Your `grid-pad` is adding padding-left:20px and your nav wrap has padding-right:20px so I'd strip them all... or you'll prob get imperfect results.

Comment: I still can't get equal distances though between the image and the nav and the right side of viewport and the nav.  http://jsfiddle.net/STL6y/